# PostgreSQL: optimization of query for select with overlap

Tags: postgresql, optimization, indexing, overlap

I create the following query for selection data with overlapping periods (for campaigns, which have the same business identifier!):

```
select 
   campaign_instance_1.campaign_id,
   campaign_instance_1.start_time
from campaign_instance as campaign_instance_1 
  inner join campaign_instance as campaign_instance_2
  on campaign_instance_1.campaign_id = campaign_instance_2.campaign_id 
  and (
      (campaign_instance_1.start_time between campaign_instance_2.start_time and campaign_instance_2.finish_time)
   or (campaign_instance_1.finish_time between campaign_instance_2.start_time and campaign_instance_2.finish_time)
   or (campaign_instance_1.start_time<campaign_instance_2.start_time and campaign_instance_1.finish_time>campaign_instance_2.finish_time)
   or (campaign_instance_1.start_time>campaign_instance_2.start_time and campaign_instance_1.finish_time<campaign_instance_2.finish_time))
```

With index, created as:

```
 CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS camp_inst_idx_campaign_id_and_finish_time
   ON public.campaign_instance_without_index USING btree
   (campaign_id ASC NULLS LAST, finish_time DESC NULLS LAST)
   TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Already on 100 000 rows it runs very slowly - 43 seconds!

For optimization I tried to add index on start_time:

```
  (campaign_id ASC NULLS LAST, finish_time DESC NULLS LAST, start_time DESC NULLS LAST)
```

But result is the same.

As I understand results of explain analyze, index "start_time" doesn't uses as a Index Condition:

I tried the query with this index either with 10 000 and 100 000 rows - so, as possible, it does not depends on sample size (at least on this scales).

Source table contains the following structure:

```
campaign_id bigint,
fire_time bigint,
start_time bigint,
finish_time bigint,
recap character varying,
details json
```

Why my index is not used, and what possible ways to improve the query?

[image: query plan]

Comment: Maybe you should instead do this with an EXISTS query or Lateral? Would you care to supply some sample data.

Comment: I update query with some details of source table.

Comment: I don't see any sample added. Did you try with exists?

Comment: You should post text as formatted text, not as images.  Especially not as images which have been truncated, and don't show proper formatting

Comment: Every row is going to find itself, so this query is unlikely to make much sense.  Does the table not have a primary key you can use to exclude self-matches?

Comment: The key to finding things fast here is probably a gist index over a built-in range type (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INDEXING).  But you really need to figure out a realistic example first.

Comment: @jjanes, condition on campaign_id equals has a critical sense, as it reflect a key business-demand to this task. From other hand, I don't specified this explicitly in my Ask. I have completed the question now with this aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining to campaign_instance (itself) doesn't really serve anything here other than making an "existence" check and probably your intention is not to get back duplicates for matching records. Thus you could simplify the query with EXISTS or LATERAL join. Also your join condition on time could be simplified, you seem to be looking for overlapping times:

```
select campaign_id,start_time
from campaign_instance c1
    where exists( select * from campaign_instance c2
        where c1.campaign_id = c2.campaign_id
  and (c1.start_time <= c2.finish_time and c1.finish_time >= c2.start_time));
```

That time overlap probably would use < and > instead of <= and >= but I don't know your exact requirements, between is implicitly saying it is <= and >=.

EDIT: Ensure that the match is not the row itself:
(This table should have a primary key to make things easier, but as it doesn't, I would assume that there is no duplication on campaign_id, start_time and finish_time and that could be used as a composite key)

```
select campaign_id,start_time
from campaign_instance c1
    where exists( select * from campaign_instance c2
        where c1.campaign_id = c2.campaign_id
  and (c1.start_time != c2.start_time or c1.finish_time != c2.finish_time)
  and (c1.start_time <= c2.finish_time and c1.finish_time >= c2.start_time));
```

This takes around 230-250 milliseconds on my system (iMac i5 7500, 3.4 Ghz, 64 Gb mem).

Comment: Concerning  join condition simplification: does suggested condition cover the case, when one period "contained" inside other? In my variant this case was cover by "c1.start_time > c2.start_time and c1.finish_time < c2.finish_time"

Comment: @Andrew, it covers all types of overlaps including edge touch only too (ie: 10-11 and 11-12 overlaps touching at 11).

Comment: Suggested solution allowed to reduce the execution time from 43 to 13 seconds.

Comment: @Andrew, and note that it also eliminates duplication of rows (ie: if 10 - 17 matches to 10-11, 11-20, 12-17 then you would get back 3 rows with the same id and 10-17 in original query). BTW, still 13 seconds looks slow to me. Maybe your environment and how and where you call it is also playing a role in it. I assumed you had an index on campaign_id.

Comment: I run the query locally, using pgAdmin. Index on campaign_id is declared, but in updated query it also don't used as a condition. From the explain output: "Hash Cond: (c1.campaign_id = c2.campaign_id)"

Comment: Oh I don't use pgAdmin since 4 update, it might the reason of slowness I don't know.

Comment: Does the format of compared data (biginit) may be the reason on slowly execution?

Comment: No. You are experiencing the slowness. I don't, even on a larger sample data set I created for testing.

Comment: @Andrew, I just tried with pgAdmin4, it takes 170-450 milliseconds on 100,000 rows data (my data distribution may have much more overlaps then yours).

Comment: @CetinBasoz  I agree his formulation doesn't make much sense, but yours makes even less as every row will find the existence of itself, which of course has the same campaign_id as itself and also an overlapping range with itself.  So it could just reduce to `select * from campaign_instance`.

Comment: @jjanes, condition on campaign_id equals has a critical sense, as it reflect a key business-demand to this task. From other hand, I don't specified this explicitly in my Ask. I have completed the question now with this aspect.

Comment: @Andrew, you are right I missed that. It would be easier as if this table had a primary  key (and it should) but anyways assuming (campaign_id, start_time, finish_time) is unique I edited to cover that. Still it is fast. BTW, on my system it takes 230-250 milliseconds, and on the same system with pgAdmin4 it takes around 310-450 milliseconds.

Comment: @CetinBasoz, i misled you! My queries executed not on local db, but on db in Kubernetes cluster. My pgAdmin connected with this cluster by port-forward. Now I'm able to take a dump of real db (with contains much more than 100 000 rows), and execute this query locally